# Trying to find out the current location of the device, it is showing "MissingPluginException"

Tags: flutter, exception, location

I have a simple piece of code, main.dart. Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. I am using

> geolocator: ^5.1.3

I am simply trying to get the location of the user. But it is showing:

> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method checkPermissionStatus on channel com.baseflow.flutter/location_permissions)
>
> A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
> 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
> Failed assertion: line 285 pos 10: 'data != null'

I have added these lines to my AndroidManifest as well:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

My main.dart code is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager;

  Position _currentPosition;
  String _currentAddress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Location"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            if (_currentPosition != null) Text(_currentAddress),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text("Get location"),
              onPressed: () {
                _getCurrentLocation();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _getCurrentLocation() {
    geolocator
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
        .then((Position position) {
      setState(() {
        _currentPosition = position;
      });

      _getAddressFromLatLng();
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }

  _getAddressFromLatLng() async {
    try {
      List<Placemark> p = await geolocator.placemarkFromCoordinates(
          _currentPosition.latitude, _currentPosition.longitude);

      Placemark place = p[0];

      setState(() {
        _currentAddress =
        "${place.locality}, ${place.postalCode}, ${place.country}";
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you run Flutter Clean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your project running on Android X? Try doing so.

Here is another helpful link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14137

Answer (score 0):

Close vscode (or android) studio and then open it and run the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to close the app and rebuild